# Convert list of paths to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, filepath

I'm making a program in Python where I need to interact with "hypothetical" paths, (aka paths that don't and won't exist on the actual filesystem) and I need to be able to `listdir` them like normal (`path['directory']` would return every item inside the directory like `os.listdir()`).

The solution I came up with was to convert a list of string paths to a dictionary of dictionaries. I came up with this recursive function (it's inside a class):

```py
    def DoMagic(self,paths):
        structure = {}
        if not type(paths) == list:
            raise ValueError('Expected list Value, not '+str(type(paths)))
        for i in paths:
            print(i)
            if i[0] == '/': #Sanity check
                print('trailing?',i) #Inform user that there *might* be an issue with the input.
                i[0] = ''
            i = i.split('/') #Split it, so that we can test against different parts.
            if len(i[1:]) > 1: #Hang-a-bout, there's more content!
                structure = {**structure, **self.DoMagic(['/'.join(i[1:])])}
            else:
                structure[i[1]] = i[1]
```

But when I go to run it with `['foo/e.txt','foo/bar/a.txt','foo/bar/b.cfg','foo/bar/c/d.txt']` as input, I get:

```
{'e.txt': 'e.txt', 'a.txt': 'a.txt', 'b.cfg': 'b.cfg', 'd.txt': 'd.txt'}
```

I want to be able to just `path['foo']['bar']` to get everything in the `foo/bar/` directory.

Edit:

A more desirable output would be:

```py
    {'foo':{'e.txt':'e.txt','bar':{'a.txt':'a.txt','c':{'d.txt':'d.txt'}}}}
```

Comment: You show the output that you don't want. Show us what the desired output is.

Comment: Ah, i didn't realize. sorry. I've added that now.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do now. I would suggest creating a `Node` class with a list of `children` and `type` flag (`file` or `directory`). Then build a tree structure mimicking the hypothetical directory structure, and a method to query the tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit 10-14-22** My first answer matches what the OP asks but isn't really the ideal approach nor the cleanest output. Since this question appears to be used more often, see a cleaner approach below that is more resilient to Unix/Windows paths and the output dictionary makes more sense.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import json

def get_path_dict(paths: list[str | Path]) -> dict:
    """Builds a tree like structure out of a list of paths"""
    def _recurse(dic: dict, chain: tuple[str, ...] | list[str]):
        if len(chain) == 0:
            return
        if len(chain) == 1:
            dic[chain[0]] = None
            return
        key, *new_chain = chain
        if key not in dic:
            dic[key] = {}
        _recurse(dic[key], new_chain)
        return

    new_path_dict = {}
    for path in paths:
        _recurse(new_path_dict, Path(path).parts)
    return new_path_dict

l1 = ['foo/e.txt', 'foo/bar/a.txt', 'foo/bar/b.cfg', Path('foo/bar/c/d.txt'), 'test.txt']
result = get_path_dict(l1)
print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "e.txt": null,
    "bar": {
      "a.txt": null,
      "b.cfg": null,
      "c": {
        "d.txt": null
      }
    }
  },
  "test.txt": null
}
```

---

**Older approach**

How about this. It gets your desired output, however a tree structure may be cleaner.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

def nested_dict():
   """
   Creates a default dictionary where each value is an other default dictionary.
   """
   return defaultdict(nested_dict)

def default_to_regular(d):
    """
    Converts defaultdicts of defaultdicts to dict of dicts.
    """
    if isinstance(d, defaultdict):
        d = {k: default_to_regular(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    return d

def get_path_dict(paths):
    new_path_dict = nested_dict()
    for path in paths:
        parts = path.split('/')
        if parts:
            marcher = new_path_dict
            for key in parts[:-1]:
               marcher = marcher[key]
            marcher[parts[-1]] = parts[-1]
    return default_to_regular(new_path_dict)
            
l1 = ['foo/e.txt','foo/bar/a.txt','foo/bar/b.cfg','foo/bar/c/d.txt', 'test.txt']
result = get_path_dict(l1)
print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "e.txt": "e.txt",
    "bar": {
      "a.txt": "a.txt",
      "b.cfg": "b.cfg",
      "c": {
        "d.txt": "d.txt"
      }
    }
  },
  "test.txt": "test.txt"
}
```

Comment: very elegant solution. Helped me a lot with something else

Comment: This throws an `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment` when I use it on my list of paths.

Comment: @Yoda If I paste the example it still works. What input are you giving it?

Comment: @Yoda, regardless that code was old and confusing. I put a newer one that should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't simple tree, implemented via dictionaries, suffice?
Your implementation seems a bit redundant. It's hard to tell easily to which folder a file belongs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)

There's a lot of libs on `pypi`, if you need something extra.
[treelib](https://treelib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

There're also `Pure paths` in [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Comment: And how does pathlib help you work with paths that don't exist?

Comment: Wouldn't simple tree, implemented via dictionaries, suffice?

Comment: @Aran-Fey the paths don't have to exist for pathlib to work, aside from the methods that check/require existence of course

Comment: There're both `pure paths` and `concrete paths`.