# Convert list of path-like strings to nested dictionary of lists (arbitrary depth)

Tags: python, parsing, recursion

The following is sample input data (real data may have more levels than shown here, hence why the solution should work for an arbitrary depth):

```
['/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-V-0546',
 '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-V-0148',
 '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-LT-0028A/SKA_20-LI-0028A',
 '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-LT-0028A/SKA_20-LI-0028B',
 '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-PT-0034/SKA_20-PI-0034',
 '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-V-0685',
 '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-V-0551']
```

I would like to turn this into a nested dictionary to store the hierarchical structure of the paths, where each parent directory becomes a dict key and all files become elements in a list.

## The desired outcome

```json
{
  "SKA_20-VA-001": [
    "SKA_20-V-0546",
    "SKA_20-V-0148",
    "SKA_20-V-0685",
    "SKA_20-V-0551",
    {"SKA_20-LT-0028A": ["SKA_20-LI-0028A", "SKA_20-LI-0028B"]},
    {"SKA_20-PT-0034": ["SKA_20-PI-0034"]}
  ]
}
```

I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58917078/6218849) answer, but it does not really solve my question. Or I am not able to modify it correctly.

Comment: You could use the method from the other thread you mentioned and collapse the dictionary for entries that only contain one element afterwards.

Comment: I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the other code due to the use of defaultdict and the `marcher`. A code example would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure, that your desired output is actually correct? Your use of lists and dictionaries seems very inconsistent.

Comment: Let me double check if I made a mistake (EDIT: updated desired outcome). I wanted all files to exist in lists, and all directories to be keys. If there is a better way of representing a hierarchy, then I am open to that.

Answer (score 0):

Such a structure is much easier to build, if you treat files like directories. After building it, you can still convert that into the list/dict combination that you were looking for.

In this case, elements without any children (`{}`) are expected to be files:

```
def add_path(tree, split_path):
    subtree = tree.setdefault(split_path[0], {})
    if len(split_path) > 1:
        add_path(subtree, split_path[1:])


def parse_tree(paths):
    tree = {}
    for path in paths:
        add_path(tree, path.split("/"))
    return tree


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(parse_tree(
        ['/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-V-0546',
         '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-V-0148',
         '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-LT-0028A/SKA_20-LI-0028A',
         '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-LT-0028A/SKA_20-LI-0028B',
         '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-PT-0034/SKA_20-PI-0034',
         '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-V-0685',
         '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-V-0551']
    ))
```

results in

```
{
  "": {
    "SKA_20-VA-001": {
      "SKA_20-V-0546": {},
      "SKA_20-V-0148": {},
      "SKA_20-LT-0028A": {
        "SKA_20-LI-0028A": {},
        "SKA_20-LI-0028B": {}
      },
      "SKA_20-PT-0034": {
        "SKA_20-PI-0034": {}
      },
      "SKA_20-V-0685": {},
      "SKA_20-V-0551": {}
    }
  }
}
```

If you need help converting this structure into the exact one you asked for, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The package "extradict" has a `NestedData` class which can arrange for this.
Unfortunatelly, as of now, the path separator is hard-coded to a dot (`.`) , meaning you have to replace the `/` in your data before feeding it (and also, strip the leading `/`).

After that, I think it can do everything you need. It will be simplear if your leaf paths are also "paths" but mapping to `None` - but if you need then to be simple strings, that could also be done.

All in all, the code is this:

```
from extradict import NestedData

data = ['/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-V-0546',
 '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-V-0148',
 '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-LT-0028A/SKA_20-LI-0028A',
 '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-LT-0028A/SKA_20-LI-0028B',
 '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-PT-0034/SKA_20-PI-0034',
 '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-V-0685',
 '/SKA_20-VA-001/SKA_20-V-0551']

d1 = [d.replace("/", ".") for d in data]
d2 = NestedData(dict.fromkeys(d1))

print(d2)
```

will print:

```
{'SKA_20-VA-001': {
    'SKA_20-V-0546': <NoneType>,
    'SKA_20-V-0148': <NoneType>,
    'SKA_20-LT-0028A': {
        'SKA_20-LI-0028A': <NoneType>,
        'SKA_20-LI-0028B': <NoneType>},
    'SKA_20-PT-0034': {'SKA_20-PI-0034': <NoneType>},
    'SKA_20-V-0685': <NoneType>,
    'SKA_20-V-0551': <NoneType>}}
```

And if you need the data structure as plain dicts, just use the `.data` attribute on d2:

```
In [33]: print(d2.data)
{'SKA_20-VA-001': {'SKA_20-V-0546': None, 'SKA_20-V-0148': None, 'SKA_20-LT-0028A': {'SKA_20-LI-0028A': None, 'SKA_20-LI-0028B': None}, 'SKA_20-PT-0034': {'SKA_20-PI-0034': None}, 'SKA_20-V-0685': None, 'SKA_20-V-0551': None}}
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of `extradict`. You can install it with `pip install extradict` - current version is 0.6